# split function in Ansible conditioning

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a varible if some other variable exists with particular value.

```
- set_fact: "var_B=somevalue"
  when: "var_A is defined and var_A.split(':')[0] > 2"
```

This doesnot work. any soultions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to get some number from var_A, correct?
Like `5` from string `5:8:9:3`.

In this case you should do type cast:

```
- set_fact: "var_B=somevalue"
  when: "var_A is defined and var_A.split(':')[0]|int > 2"
```

Note `|int` filter applied.

Otherwise you compare string `"5"` and number `2`.
In Python (which is under the hood of Ansible) string is always greater than integer.